# admin menu naming

Tags: php, admin-menu

how can I change the 1st child name of the admin menu in wp? I have upload a picture, I want to have a different name of the 1st child of the menu and the parent will be the same.

[image]

this is mycode

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'mymenu_admin_actions');
function mymenu_admin_actions(){
    add_menu_page('Axcelerate Client Link', 'Axcelerate Client Link', 'manage_options', 'Axcelerate_Link_Admin', 'axcelerate_link_admin_page');

    add_submenu_page('Axcelerate_Link_Admin','Page Setup','Page Setup', 'manage_options','Axcelerate_Link_Admin_Pages_Setup','axcelerate_link_admin_pages_setup_page');

}
```

what I really want is to be link this:

```
Axecelerate Client Link
- Link Admin
- Page Setup
```

is this possible?

Comment: try `add_menu_page('Axcelerate Client Link', 'Link Admin', 'manage_options', 'Axcelerate_Link_Admin', 'axcelerate_link_admin_page');`

Answer (score 0):

If this Plugin from your side, then change the strings in the functions.

If not, then write a custom plugin, hook in `admin_menu` and parse the global `$submenu`. In this array are all values of the menu, smaller level 1. All parent items are stored in the global `$menu`.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_menu_item' );
function change_menu_item() {
    global $menu, $submenu;

    // understand the array
    var_dump( $menu );
}
```

Alternatively is the filter `gettext`. But is often a performance topic, check this again the fist idea.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_menu_item' );
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'change_menu_item' );

function change_menu_item( $translated ) {

    $translated = str_replace( 'Post', 'Article', $translated );
    $translated = str_replace( 'post', 'article', $translated );

    return $translated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-your-wordpress-admin--wp-24941) may help you to achieve your goal.

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-your-wordpress-admin--wp-24941

example would be like below,

```
function edit_admin_menus() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;

    $menu[5][0] = 'Recipes'; // Change Posts to Recipes
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'All Recipes';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add a Recipe';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_admin_menus' );
```